# How to shuffle an array with a seed value by using npm modules in angular ?(like e.g;shuffle-seed )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, shuffle

I am shuffling an array with below algorithm,

```
  let _sectionItems=section.items;

  if (this.testType === this._testType) {
      let i = 0, j = 0, temp = null;
      for (i = section.items.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
          j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
          temp = section.items[i];
          section.items[i] = section.items[j]
          section.items[j] = temp
          //   this.sectionItems.push(_sectionItems);
          // console.log("shuffing items:",section.items[j]);
      }
  }
```

Later the requirement change, right now I wanted to shuffle an array with a seed value. Instead of math.random(). How to get randomize an array with seed value. How to achieve that in typescript. I am using typescript because angular 4.